# Are there any consequences when a room is on fire?

Tags: fallout-shelter

My living quarters (barracks) got on fire but nobody was in there. After a while the fire extinguished by itself. It did spread to other rooms with dwellers in it though, but they quickly subdued the flames.

Are there any (permanent) consequences or penalties when a room is on fire and not extinguished by dwellers but by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fires that are not attended to can lead to dweller deaths. Additionally, they stop production while they are fighting the fires, and, as you already know, can spread fairly quickly throughout the entire vault.

Comment: But only dwellers that are present in the room could die right?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid yes, only the dwellers that are in the room that is currently on fire. Larger rooms take longer to extinguish, and if the fire spreads through the vault, it can put your entire vault at risk.

Comment: Upgrades contribute significantly more to incident difficulty than room size.  A 3 square level 1 room is easier to put out (assuming full capacity) than a 1 square level 3 room.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

Fires that extinguish by itself leave no effective penalty.  Your room is burnt but it doesn't affect the statistics of the room or anything in your shelter at all.

This is one of the tactics I use to maintain 50 population in a large shelter.  I build rooms in sections separated by walls (dirt), so incidents extinguish by themselves and do not spread through the whole base.